# Easily Automate Load/Performance tests | Azure ASP.NET Web App

Tags: asp.net, performance, azure, automated-tests, azure-devops

Setting up automated unit-tests with Azure has been a breeze..

However, I'm running into some walls trying to setup some load/performance tests for my Web App.

Could anyone provide a simple tutorial for setting up automated load/performance tests in Azure?  To start I just want something very simple to automate.

I'm not sure if I should be using 1) Azure's Performance Tests, 2) Visual Studio's cloud-based load testing, 3) A Visual Studio Web Performance / Load Test Project (.csproj), 4) A build step in my Visual Studio Team Services build definition (this is how I'm currently automating unit tests), or 5) something else??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out a technique

1) Record a Test Using Chrome, this can be done from the (dev tools) network tab, make sure that Preserve Log is checked.  Now you can use the actual site and browser to record a UI test.

2) You can export the Test by Right Clicking on the list of network calls and clicking on 'Save as HAR with Content'.

3) In VSTS, I can then go to my Load Tests and create a new Load Test, and click New and then HTTP Archive Based Test and select the .HAR file you saved.

4) Now everything can be automated from VSTS and via a VSTS Build step, etc.

5) From VSTS you can also Export to Visual Studios, which will create the necessary C# files for creating a Test Project.

6) You can create a 'Load' test based on your performance test in Visual Studios.

Visual Studios is really becoming a one stop shop for everything awesome.

Answer (score 0):

[There](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/load-test/overview) is a good article with detail steps to do cloud load test and you can [create/start/stop test](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/load-test/test-runs#create-a-test-run) run through Rest API.

1. Create a valid loadtest file. You can use the load test file from an earlier run through Visual Studio for this.
2. Create a location to upload the file(s). This location is a drop folder on Azure Blob and is below referred to as "TestDrop".
3. Upload the loadtest file and any other files required for the run, this includes the webtest files, settings file, etc. to this location or "TestDrop".
4. Create a Test Run using the Testdrop from the previous step as all the files required for a run are now available at the drop location.
5. Start the run.
6. Once finished, download the results to your local machine. This will be a gzip file. Uncompress it to get the results file.
7. Use Visual Studio to view the downloaded results.

[image]